# Listen for new added properties on a computed function

Tags: ember.js

I have the following object:

```
{ 
types: ["Type A", "Type B", "Type C"],
colours: ["Red", "Blue", "Black"]
}
```

which I send as parameter to a component

```
export default Ember.component.extend({
  tableContent: function(){
  const keys = Object.keys(this.get('config'));
  if (keys.length > 1){
    let array = [];
    keys.shift();
    keys.forEach((element) => {
     array.pushObject({name: element});
    });
    return array;
  }
}.property('config')
```

I want to be able to listen for changes when creating a new addition. Ex:

```
{ 
types: ["Type A", "Type B", "Type C"],
colours: ["Red", "Blue", "Black", "Yellow"].
lang: ["en","fr","es"]
}
```

I have tried using .property('config.@each') but it wont work.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`config` is an object, so `config.types.@each` will work.
You can listen for all `config.types.@each` `config.colours.@each` `config.lang.@each` or it can be shortened to something like this `config.{types,colours,lang}.@each`

Refer : https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.16.0/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/